# How can a Muslim woman indicate her willingness to be an obedient wife to a prospective husband?

Tags: women, relationships, husband

[NewMuslims.com](http://www.newmuslims.com/lessons/158/) lists five qualities Muslim men should look for when seeking a wife: 1. Taqwa (piety), 2. Affectionate nature, 3. Obedience, 4. Patience, 5. Contentment.

If a Muslim woman was interested in a particular man becoming her future husband, it would therefore be good for her to demonstrate these qualities to him.  It seems difficult to demonstrate a willingness to become an obedient wife, however.

**Question**: How can a Muslim woman indicate her willingness to be an obedient wife to a prospective husband?

My impression is that Muslim men seem to value obedience.  RomanticMuslim.com [7 Things Your Muslim Husband Won’t Tell You](http://romanticmuslim.com/7-things-your-muslim-husband-wont-tell/) writes "above all, he desires your respect" and even quotes [Qur'an 3:43](https://quran.com/4/34) "...So righteous women are devoutly obedient, guarding in [the husband’s] absence what Allah would have them guard...".

Comment: He has to ask...she has to reply and speak her mind. Perhaps asking some specific questions like what would do if I said X...and she reply I would do Y...

Answer (score 1):

She can either express her willingness to be an obedient wife verbally and explicitly, or demonstrate it through her actions during the courtship period; different ways she can demonstrate this:

- Genuinely respect him.
- Defer decision-making to him (however trivial the decision); don't tell him what to do, let him make the decisions.
- Don’t criticize his decisions.
- Show him that he has your full trust and support, even when you don’t agree with him.